# Collection Variable as Dynamic Choices/Choices in Visual Workflow

Tags: visual-workflow

Is there a way to use a collection variable for a dynamic choices/choices element within the flow?

ex. I have a collection variable "numbers" within the flow that I've already populated with (1,2,3) values. Can you use those collection variable values(1,2,3) as choices for a drop down list in a screen?

NOTE: Collection Variable values would be dynamic, values can change.