# Visual Workflow: Creating Choices from a Collection

Tags: picklist, visual-workflow

I'm creating a visual workflow and trying to add a dynamic dropdown. Through a loop that looks up records in one field based on parameters passed in the URL, I've saved the values into a collection variable. But I'm having trouble using that collection as my dropdown choices.

Looking at the three choice options:

1. Choice - Doesn't take collections at all
2. Dynamic Record Choice - Looks up on a sObj. The problem with this is, my list has pulled from multiple sObj
3. Picklist Choice - Same as Dynamic Record choice; looks up to a single sObj.

All I want to be able to do is to create a list of choices from a collection. Is this not possible?

Thank you!

NOTE: This seems to be a duplicate of [Collection Variable as Dynamic Choices/Choices in Visual Workflow](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69924/collection-variable-as-dynamic-choices-choices-in-visual-workflow), except there is no answer there either.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to write to a temp holding object so you create records, query and use in dynamic choice, and then delete when done.  A lot of lifting for what could be a much lighter solution if it was possible to use collection directly in choice / dynamic choice.

Comment: Also note that I beleive its not possible to directly use collection.  If someone knows a way I would love to see it!

Comment: Totally Agree! I'm not certain that this visual workflow is easier to use rather than learning apex!

Comment: You don't have to write test classes!  It's a good point.  Pushing flows to their limits may point at moving to code, but you can do some pretty cool stuff relatively easily.  But relying on anything that is built in flash makes me think twice.  That said you can combine apex plugins w flows so that the logic is handled by apex but could prob just go all in at that point.

Comment: What is a good use case of using a mixture of visual flow and apex? I find that everything you do in visual flow can more easily be done in straight code. The only reason to try to use visual flow is if you want non technical users to be able to edit the flows. Once you add code to a flow, you introduce the requirement of a developer. Is there a good use case of using both together?

Comment: If you are a strong coder then I think that balance would be heavily tilted to code.  One place I've seen combined is where you want a flow w screens to do something in system mode, BC user doesn't have access to it.  Also Keir Bowden explores some use cases here. http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2015/02/lightning-process-builder-and-invocable.html?m=1. I find flows easier primarily bc i am not a good coder.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's a good article. I'm just not used to the Salesforce dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled up on this old thread. If somebody needs to set up a dynamic Dropdown menu with a collection today, then use this Flow component:

https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please, read [tour] and [answer]. It would be great if you could expand your answer to provide more info without relying on external resources.

Comment: Prezemyslaw, I'm a Salesforce product manager and the author of the component that Clifford is recommending here. 
I'm sympathetic to the desire of Stack Exchange to provide complete answers and guidance to new contributors and appreciate that you're on the frontline helping welcome new contributors. 
In this case, Clifford's answer is exactly correct: go and install that component. I don't see a way that Clifford could reasonably follow your recommendation here.